# Why won't this PHP & SQL user login work?

Tags: php, sql

I am building a website for my course and I can't get the user login to work. I have managed to get the account creation working and I have checked they're being made by querying the database but the login still won't work. I have tested all the forms and they're working properly. I am using sqlite3 for my database.

In particular, all the values seem to be stored correctly yet when I log in (or at least attempt to) I am redirected to the settings page which means that the passwords have not matched each other. So there must be something wrong there because it finds the correct user.

Account Creation PHP:

```
<?php

        require 'database.php';
        $username = $_POST['user_username'];
        $password = $_POST['user_password'];
        $email = $_POST['user_email'];
        $salt = sha1(time());
        $password = sha1($password);
        $encrypted_password = ($salt."--".$password);


        $db = new Database();
        $db->exec("INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL, '$username', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', '$email');");

        header("Refresh: 5;url=http://cs139.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~u1418925/cs139/index.php");
        echo "<center><h1>You will be rediected in 5 seconds...</h1></center>"

?>
```

Account Login PHP:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        require 'database.php';
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];
        $password = $_POST['user_password'];

        $db = new Database();
        $row = $db->querySingle("SELECT * from users WHERE(username = '$username');");

        $password = sha1(password);
        if(($row['salt']."--".$password) == $row['password']) {
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
                header('Location:index.php');
        } else {
                header('Location:settings.php');
        }
?>
```

Database.php:

```
<?php
class Database {

    private $database;

    function __construct() {
        $this->database = $this->getConnection();
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->database->close();
    }

    function exec($query) {
        $this->database->exec($query);
    }

    function query($query) {
        $result = $this->database->query($query);
        return $result;
    }

    function querySingle($query) {
        $result = $this->database->querySingle($query,true);
        return $result;
    }

    function prepare($query) {
        return $this->database->prepare($query);
    }

    function escapeString($string) {
        return $this->database->escapeString($string);
    }

    private function getConnection() {
        $conn = new SQLite3('todo.db');
        return $conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Be more specific than `it doesnt work.`

Comment: This question is a little too broad as it is.  What research have you done already? What isn't working? Are there any errors? What have you done to debug the problem? As it stands, it just seems like you're saying "Here's my homework, complete it for me".  Be a little more specific in your questioning.

Comment: Did you try removing `;` form the end of your query????

Comment: Yeah sorry for that, I have been a lot more specific now. I don't wish for you to complete it by any means, I have done quite a bit and there is far more to do besides this I have just been stuck on this for a while and I can't get any help from the postgrads till monday.

Comment: This code has SQL injection vulnerabilities in it - don't go live until they are fixed. At present, any security you implement might be bypassable anyway. If your database library offers parameter binding, use that - if it does not, switch to a library that does. PDO offers a SQLite driver.

Comment: we can't see the field names obviously, is `$row['password']` the correct field name or is it `$row['encrypted_password']` the same as your variable name?

Comment: The field name is just password. I am sorry, it is a little un-clear. I know.

Comment: Still what doesnt work mean?It doesnt output anything?Does it go here  `header('Location:settings.php');`?Does it give an error?

Comment: Yes that's what it does which still means that the passwords don't match

Comment: You have a typo `$password = sha1(password);` should be `$password = sha1($password);` missing the $

Comment: Yeah sorry that's just in the code on stack it's not in my actual code.

Comment: To make sure the rest of the code is NOT executed add an exit(); after your first redirect `header('Location:index.php');exit();`

Comment: I added that, it doesn't seem to be the issue either I can't see a problem anywhere

Comment: If you echo this out `$row['salt']."--".$password` does it match encrypted_password?

Comment: Have you checked the value of your `$_POST` vars to make sure they are giving you what you expect? You should be able to debug this by putting in `var_dump()` and `die()` statements along the way to see why it fails. For example, what are the values in `$row['salt']`,  `$password`, and `$row['password']`?

Comment: I checked them and they all give the expected values. When I echo it the two salt pars are the same but the password parts differ. e.g the parts after the --

Comment: Is it possible that you have the same `username` twice in the table? Make sure the column `username` is unique in the table.

Comment: Also are you sure its the same pass?

Comment: Yes its the same pass and there isn't a username repeat in the table.

Comment: Insert a new user and echo out the `sha1($password)` before the insert and then compare with the inserted value in the database. If they match, then the second part of logging in should be straight forward. Echo out the two values as above when logging in and they have to match. You can test the value of `sha1($password)` at any point along the way to see where it is getting messed up.

Comment: ok I basically have it working now through repeated messing around, but for some reason my post method is no longer giving me a password its just leaving a blank value. As soon as I fix that it should work.